# Editing Text file header (Fasta format)

Tags: command-line, text-editor

This is a fasta format heading

```
>KRH76248 pep chromosome:Glycine_max_v2.1:1:47401227:47414434:-1 gene:GLYMA_01G141900 transcript:KRH76248 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical protein
MQKGREVRDNNIFEPRRFEDFGDFGFHRSRMPSLFGGRDPFDDPFFTDPFDSLFGPSSAS
RAMQKTNREKGIVIEEIDSDDEGADNGPETGEKDFDKKKSKSTMEPSIEYPDDDVNERKN
SDVTYKNDHCMAEPKARKFSFQTSRVTYGGIDGAYYTSTRIRRMGANGEVMEENKEADTT
TGQASHRRITRGIHDKGHSVLRKLDSDGKVDTTQTLHNLNEDELAGFEEAWKGNNMAQLP
GFDVHRKEGTMLT
```

Out of that I want keep only >GLYMA_01G141900 followed by sequences and the remaining part need to be deleted.

Expected result

```
>GLYMA_01G141900
MQKGREVRDNNIFEPRRFEDFGDFGFHRSRMPSLFGGRDPFDDPFFTDPFDSLFGPSSAS
RAMQKTNREKGIVIEEIDSDDEGADNGPETGEKDFDKKKSKSTMEPSIEYPDDDVNERKN
SDVTYKNDHCMAEPKARKFSFQTSRVTYGGIDGAYYTSTRIRRMGANGEVMEENKEADTT
TGQASHRRITRGIHDKGHSVLRKLDSDGKVDTTQTLHNLNEDELAGFEEAWKGNNMAQLP
GFDVHRKEGTMLT
```

I have 85000 thousand different sequences with a different heading, So how to proceed in the command line. Thank you in advance

For help I found one command

```
sed -r '/>/S/.\gene:(.) transcript:.*/>\1/'test.fa
```

Comment: I updated the formatting, but I'm not sure it's still correct. Do both the input and output begin with the `>` character?

Comment: Thank you for formatting, It is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution using tr and awk:

```
tr -d '\n' < inputfile | awk -F':'  '{OFS="\n";print $7,$11}' | tr -d 'a-z' > outputfile
```

Comment: Than you for the solution. When I ran the command, got this result                                    awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
 FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1

Comment: Ah I used a file with just one record -- the one you provided. You can try that first. That single record contains 12 fields (number 7 is the heading and number 12 is the sequence). If all your records are in a single file then we would have to find a way of repeating the process for each record. I will need to  think about how to automate this! In fact awk is ideal for handling very large number of records repetitively.  in the meantime can you provide a sample of  two acquisitive records so I know how they are separated.

Comment: >KRH76251 pep chromosome:Glycine_max_v2.1:1:47410093:47414021:-1 gene:GLYMA_01G141900 transcript:KRH76251 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical protein
MQKGREVNIFEPRRFEDFGDFGFHRSRMPSLFGGRDPFDDPFFTDPFDSLFGPSSASRAMQKTNREKGIVIEEIDSDDEGADNGPETGEKDFDKKKSKSTMEPSIEYP >KRH77790 pep chromosome:Glycine_max_v2.1:1:56016502:56018849:-1 gene:GLYMA_01G234000 transcript:KRH77790 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical protein
MVSIISTNNQCNPSHISHGGGGGAIGVRGLDEDDDDDVGKNEEENKWPPWLGPLLQTSFFVQCKVHADSHKSECNMYCLDCMNGALC

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want

```
sed -E '/^>/s/.* gene:(\S+).*/>\1/' file
```

`-E` and `-r` are equivalent, but I prefer `-E` since it corresponds to the same grep option.

`\S+` is "one or more non-whitespace characters" in GNU sed.

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thank you very much for your assistance. How to find the output file?

Comment: That command does not produce a file, it just prints to stdout. You need to redirect the output to a file if you need one.

Comment: Thank you, I have done it

Comment: After analysis, in a file, I got a repetitive sequences. Example 
>GLYMA_01G141900
MQKGREVRDNNIFEPRRFEDFGDFGFHRSRMPSLFGGRDPFDDPFFTDPFDSLFGPSSASRAMQKTNREKGIVIEEIDSDDEGADNGPETGEKDFDKKKSKSTMEPSIEYPDDDVNERKNSDVTYKNDHCMAEPKARKFSFQTSRVTYGGIDGAYYTSTRIRRMGANGEVMEENKEADTTTGQASHR
>GLYMA_01G141900
MQKGREVRDNNIFEPRRFEDFGDFGFHRSRMPSLFGGRDPFDDPFFTDPFDSLFGPSSASRAMQKTNREKGIVIEEIDSDDEGADNGPETGEKDFDKKKSKSTMEPSIEYPDDDVNERKNSDVTYKNDHCMAEPKARKFSFQTSRVTYGGIDGAYYTSTRIRRMGANGEVMEENKEADTTTGQASHRRITR How to eliminate duplicates and maintain only one sequence through out file? @Glenn jackman

Comment: That cannot be done with sed. I'd use Perl or awk for that.

Comment: Ok Thank you for update

Answer (score 1):

1. first get rid of artificial 'end of line' markers in your file (I called it raw):

   cat raw | tr -d '\n'
2. I noticed that conveniently every record starts with the character > (i.e. right angled bracket). So I used these to flag a new line '\n'

   tr  ">" "\n"
3. now every record is on a single line. The first line is blank. To delete that I used sed command:

   sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
4. We are now ready to use awk. It needs to read each record (line) and extract what we want. There are 11 fields in each record. Again conveniently the Fields are separated by the character ':'  hence -F':' option below:

   awk -F':'  '{OFS="\n";print $7,$11}'

(OFS is the output field separator -- here we simply want the header to be on one line and its gene sequence below it - hence  OFS="\n" in the command)

5. And finally we want to get rid of some left-over lower-case characters:

   tr -d 'a-z '

Putting it all together here is the full command:

```
cat raw | tr -d '\n' | tr  ">" "\n" | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' | awk -F':'  '{OFS="\n";print $7,$11}' | tr -d 'a-z '
```

if you want the final result in a new file (say myoutput) simply add a redirection command to myoutput.

Comment: Thank you...It worked